# How to mock a server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server, integration-testing

I want to integration test this javascript proxy server.

```
var express = require(["express"], function(){}),
    http = require(["http"], function(){}),
    port = (process.env.PORT || 8001),
    server = module.exports = express(),
    httpProxy = require(['http-proxy'], function(){});
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
// SERVER CONFIGURATION
// ====================
server.configure(function() {
  server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.url.indexOf('/any/thing') === 0) {
      //console.log(res);
      proxy.web(req, res, {target: 'http://any.thing.com'});
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
  server.use('/anything', express["static"](__dirname + "/../public"));
  server.use(express.errorHandler({
    dumpExceptions: true,
    showStack: true
  }));
  server.use(express.bodyParser());
  server.use(server.router);
});
// Start Node.js Server
http.createServer(server).listen(port);
```

My idea is to use SinonJS to create a fake server. The web front end sends a request to the original proxy server. The request will be forwarded to the fake server, which sends back a fake response. I want to use Jasmine to write the tests.

I don't know how to set this all up. I started with a HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.2.0</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.css">

    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/boot.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine-jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/sinon.js"></script>

    <!-- libs -->
    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/require.js"></script>
    <script src="src/config.js"></script>

    <!-- Server -->
    <script src="src/server.js"></script>

    <!-- add spec files here -->

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Can I start the proxy server from within this file as done in this line `<script src="src/server.js"></script>`?

Then I would start the fake server in the spec file:

```
describe("Integration Tests", function(){

    var server;

    beforeAll(function(){
        server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
        server.autoRespond = true;
        server.respondImmediately = true;
        serverResponse([200, {}, '{}']);
    });

    function serverResponse(response){
        server.respondWith(/^https?:any.thing.com/, response);
    }

    it ("should ...", function(){
        expect(...)...
    });
});
```

Can I do this? It does not work for me, because the server cannot be started. The console gives these errors:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> Uncaught Error: Script error for: express
>
> http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>
> Failed to load resource: > the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> Uncaught Error: Script error for: http
>
> http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the problem is in your scenario, but I will suggest what worked for me in the past.

I used [nock](https://github.com/pgte/nock), the project is well documented, here is how I would configure it in your case:

```
var nock = require('nock');

var server = nock('http://your.domain.here')
  .get('/any/thing')
  .reply(200, {
    // I don't know, probably you want some content
    // so you can assert on that?
  });
```

What `nock` does is intercept all calls to `http://your.domain.here/any/thing`and return a `200` with the payload you defined.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but is there a way to do this with sinonjs? and how and where exactly do I start the server? can I do it in the html file?